# How to get JVM heap size, used memory, total memory for each user session in spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, memory, jvm, utilization

We are trying to analyze memory consumption for each user session in spring MVC application on Tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, directly at least. The heap isn't partitioned per user session and so the GC logs etc. will be for the JVM as a whole.

What you can do is use a heap dump and then something like Eclipse MAT to analyse the dump afterwards and calculate the total retained size for each of the session objects.